# How to insert a value into Set collection in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I am doing a project using Struts2 and I have a problem assigning a set collection.

Here's my Action (I eliminated the irrelevant part)

```
public class TeamAction extends BaseAction implements ModelDriven<Team>
{
 Team team=new Team();

}
```

Here's my model `Team` (I eliminated the irrelevant part)

```
private TeamId id;
private Set students = new HashSet(0);
```

Here's my JSP part

```xml
<input type="text" name=team.student[0].id />
```

Now the problem is I can't insert the right value into this `Set` collection in by `ModelDriven`, it will throw a exception. Could you please tell me what to write in JSP file, so I can insert a value to `Set` collection in my model?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23470075/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is a `Collection` and as any other collection could be indexed by a property.

```java
@Element(value = Student.class)
@Key(value = Integer.class)
@KeyProperty(value = "id") 
@CreateIfNull(value = true)
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet(0);
//getter and setter, also for Student class that should have Integer id.
```

in JSP

```jsp
<s:iterator value="students " var="student">
  <s:textfield name="students(%{#student.id}).name" />
</s:iterator>
```

---

More about this see

[Indexing a collection by a property of that collection](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#indexing-a-collection-by-a-property-of-that-collection).

> It is also possible to obtain a unique element of a
> collection by passing the value of a given property
> of that element. By default, the property of the
> element of the collection is determined in
> `<Class>->conversion.properties` using
> `KeyProperty_xxx=yyy`, where `xxx` is the property
> of the bean `Class` that returns the collection and
> `yyy` is the property of the collection element that
> we want to index on.

Comment: why we are using  `(%{#student.id})` can we use  `<s:textfield name="students[%{#student.id}].name" />` Here.

Comment: can we use same notatin  'In Jsp' for getting input for List also

Comment: @xrcwrn Did you try it yourself? I think it should give you precise answer.

Comment: Uh, new notation, nice. Does it work for retrieval too ?

Comment: They said `[]` syntax is for maps, but it's working for lists too, the above solution works for any collection.