# How to retrieve the elements of HashSet using Struts2 tag without using s:iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I am using Struts2. Please help me in understanding how to retrieve the elements of `HashSet` using Struts2 tag without using Struts iterator tag.

### struts.xml

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="bundle" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

  <action name="fetchPage">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <result name="success">/jsp/page.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="process" 
        class="sample.action.Process" 
        method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <result name="success">/jsp/result.jsp</result>
  </action>

</package>  
</struts>
```

### Process.java (Action Class)

```
package sample.action;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import sample.pojo.Customer;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Process extends ActionSupport 
{
    private Set<Customer> result = new HashSet<Customer>();

    public String execute() 
    {
        Customer cust1 = new Customer();
        cust1.setAge(59);
        cust1.setName("Subramanian");
        result.add(cust1);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Set<Customer> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Set<Customer> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

### Cutomer.java - Pojo class

```
package sample.pojo;
public class Customer{

    String name;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }   
}
```

### result.jsp - View

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;" />
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome!
 <s:textfield id="custName" value="%{result[0].name}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

With above code, I am not able to read `HashSet` object value in `result.jsp` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to retrieve the elements of `HashSet` using Struts2 tag without using `<s:iterator>`?**

By using some OGNL magic called projection.

```
<s:textfield id="custName" value="%{result.{name}[0]}" />
```

The `result.{name}` will create a list from all `name` values in the `result` and the `[0]` will retrieve first element of that list.

Note that because you are using `HashSet` iteration order is not guaranteed. Use `LinkedHashSet` to achieve predictable iteration order.

Comment: Hello, in this case, can you lost name property?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `()` notation instead of `[]`. The last is for `List` and array, or `Map`. So it's not applicable to `Set`.

```jsp
<s:textfield id="custName" value="%{result(0).name}"/>
```

---

You should add `id` property to the element's type. The `id` is a default key to map through a collection.

```java
public class Customer{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    int age;
//getter and setter
}
```

---

Initialize the `id` property along with others

```
Customer cust1 = new Customer();

cust1.setId(0);
cust1.setAge(59);
cust1.setName("Subramanian");
result.add(cust1);
```

---

You can learn more about type conversion in [Indexing a collection by a property of that collection](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion#indexing-a-collection-by-a-property-of-that-collection).

Also OGNL development guide for understanding [Indexing](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Indexing).

Comment: Thanks Roman for your time. I made changes as stated in your answer by adding id attribute to the Pojo class and setting the id value and used () instead of [] in jsp. But unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Hmm, I supposed it to work, according to the documents linked to this answer. If I need to add something to update my answer, just let me know. Also you might find helpful a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191304/573032) on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `Set` you can use

```
<s:property value="%{result.iterator.next.name}"/>
```

Or

Change the `Set` to `List`, the List has a `get` method which the set does not .

After that both below will work

```
<s:property value="%{result[0].name}"/>
<s:property value="%{result.get(0).name}"/>
```